# Should I rely on the dependency list check of react useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, react-hooks, react-fiber

Consider the following code

```
useEffect(effect, [v]) // v can be undefined
```

I want to run the `effect` function **only** after the first render or when `v` changes.

My questions are

1. Do I need to check whether `v` changes in `effect`? Or I can rely on react to check the value of the dependency list (i.e., the `[v]`).
2. If the answer of 1. is the latter, is this behavior supposed to be changed in the near future? For e.g., when the concurrent mode is released.

From [react official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

> Conditionally firing an effect
>
> The default behavior for effects is to
> fire the effect after every completed render. That way an effect is
> always recreated if one of its dependencies changes.

It says **if** `one of its dependencies changes`, **then**, `an effect is recreated`. However, it does not mention the reverse: an effect is recreated **if and only if** one of its dependencies changes.

I only remember that in the early stage of hook, I read somewhere that the `effect` function can be run in some cases even without `v`'s change, in order to optimize the memory, or in concurrent mode?? I really do not remember exactly and could not find out the source.

It would be very helpful if anyone can tell me how exactly React does, or refer to the related internal source code of react. I think they would have a special check of the first render, otherwise, when `v` is `undefined` after the first render, `effect` will not run.

Comment: I don't know enough about concurrent mode, but checking to see if `v` is updated or not is the exact purpose of the dep array, so it would be necessarily redundant--something I'm sure the react team wouldn't require of us

Comment: No need to check internally. React will check by itself. Concurrent mode experimental for 18 months - there will not be breaking changes to useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

I also posted the question on react repo [here](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/3337). The thread helped me solved my question.

Hope that it also helps others.